# Java pick a method base on a hashmap key

Tags: java, class, hashmap, maps

I have a question regarding optimizing my program in java. Right now I have a working hashmap and I want to find a way to pick a method based on the maps key. Essentially I have a class that contains the map and I have a class for each possible key. I was just going to make an if statement for each possible key and if the map contains it I would then send the key with its value to that specific class to execute some code. This would work but it feels like bad practice and my goal is to use better practices in java so I want to know whats the best way to do this without the janky cluster of if statements.

I am not exactly sure how to go about this maybe I could extend all the classes from that main class and use some form of method overloading but I think that would only work If I looped through the maps values and used their key as a parameter to overload.

Another idea I had other than looping was to send the map to all the classes and if they contain the key pass it through if not do nothing.

Comment: any suggestion??

Comment: Do you mind providing more information and code? What kind of key/value pairs are you working with? Do the methods take both key and value as parameters?

Comment: I need to send the key and the value to the right class but I dont want to make an if statement to check each class I rather find a way to pass the key and its value straight to the class is there a way to do this?

Comment: It would be much easier to give an answer if you provided some code of your map and sample class/method. Do you need the return value from the methods called for each class?

Comment: One thing I've seen before (don't know if this can be considered "best practice", but its definitely better looking code), is to have the classes of the target methods, implement an interface with a method for checking if it should be that class handling the item, and one for handling it. Then you iterate through the class instances, calling the method for checking, and run the second for the one that matches.

Comment: Another possiblity is to use a Map which takes the key and an anonymous function (mapped to value as a Supplier?) which calls the appropriate class method with a given value.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines may work for you:

```
enum SampleClass {
    CLASS1, CLASS2, CLASS3
}
```

```
Map<SampleClass, Supplier<Boolean>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(CLASS1, () -> Class1.method("value1"));
map.put(CLASS2, () -> Class2.method("value2"));
map.put(CLASS3, () -> Class3.method("value3"));

boolean result = map.get(CLASS1).get();
```

```
class Class1 {
    public static boolean method(String value) {
        // ...
    }
}
// ... and so on for every class
```